# How do I convert GMT to LocalTime in Win32 C?

Tags: c, winapi, timezone

I want to convert various location/date/times in history from GMT to local time. It seems that `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime` is better than `FileTimeToLocalFileTime`. When the  date/time pairs also include various locations, the conversion gets hairy. I've found a data set at ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/releases — was ftp://elsie.nci.nih.gov/pub/ — that seems to be nicely complete through history and space, but it appears to be designed to be compiled for one time zone instead of all of them.

`GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation` and `GetTimeZoneInformationForYear` functions are only available beginning in Vista / Server 2008 and I have machines back to NT 4.0. I will probably try to use them conditionally on the newer systems.

Is there a nice C package that will solve the problem for me for Windows XP and NT 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime is the right function for this, but you need a way to populate a complete database of TIMEZONE_INFO structures.

For details on how you can build a set of TIMEZONE_INFO structures out of the registry itself, see this thread on egghead cafe:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31656478/get-current-time-in-diffe.aspx

To get things truly correct across legislative changes, you'll need GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation and  GetTimeZoneInformationForYear.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724421(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: Thank you for your reply -- I've updated my question to reflect information you gave.